# Foundation 5 nav menu on mobile margin issue

Tags: css, html, mobile, zurb-foundation

When I view my basic Foundation 5 website in mobile there is a large spacing issue between the logo and the navigation menu links.

[view site here](http://rimrock.devinewebmedia.com/)

I'm certain this is due to the fact that I'm using class 'heady' (margin-top: 105px) for desktop to push the navigation menu down to be flush with the large banner image.

Is there a better way to align my menu so it looks good on a mobile device as well? (No whitespace gap from the margin-top style)

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a media query to force the margin value.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 40em) {
    .heady {
        margin: 0 !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added this CSS to the foundation.css file but it now seems to throw off the website when viewed on a non-mobile device...any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Spacing in between the logo and nav-links is because of the large-6 columns which take up 100% space on small screens.making both the columns stack one after the other. 
try this

```
<div class="large-6 small-6 columns">
        <a href="http://rimrock.devinewebmedia.com/"><h1><img src="img/rimrock_200x132.png" width="200" height="132" style="margin-top:10px;"></h1></a>
      </div>
 <div class="large-6 small-6 columns heady tk-proxima-nova">
                <ul class="inline-list right">
        <li><a href="https://investor.omnium.com/">Client Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>  
      </ul>
    </div>
```

and set margin by changing the below css as it makes nav-links align to top

```
@media screen and (max-width: 40em) {
.heady {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
}
```